# PSTricks code automatically generated by GeoGebra doesn't comple?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add, geogebra

I'm trying to make illustrations for a paper and I don't have much time for it so I don't have time to learn a full language so I got to know that GeoGebra has the possibility to auto-generate code. Here is the result I'd like to achieve (darker region=part I want to keep):

[image]

And here is the auto-generated code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=5pt 0,linewidth=2.pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-0.75,-0.2)(2.5,1.8)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=0.2,Dy=0.2,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-0.75,-0.2)(2.5,1.8)
\psplot[linewidth=2.pt]{-0.75}{2.5}{(--1.92-1.2*x)/1.6}
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=1pt 1pt](0.,0.)(0.576,0.768)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=1pt 1pt](-0.4,1.19677)(-0.4,0.)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=1pt 1pt](0.992,0.456)(1.4,1.)
\begin{scriptsize}
\rput[bl](-1.2222293167219342,2.0250662487315707){Iperpiano}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](0.,0.)
\rput[bl](0.347674159199165,0.33990526238231566){$\scalebox{1.5}{\boldsymbol{\cfrac{b}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}}$}
\psdots[dotsize=4pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](0.,1.2)
\rput[bl](0.01742007432551912,1.2396098567891212){\darkgray{$D$}}
\rput[bl](-0.5330034004638906,0.5826826926190728){$\scalebox{1.5}{\boldsymbol{b}}$}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](1.4,1.)
\rput[bl](1.4676662731184857,0.9444686670895343){$\scalebox{1.5}{\boldsymbol{x^{(i)}}$}
\rput[bl](1.2570694653729724,0.6826498697753844){$\scalebox{1.5}{\boldsymbol{d^{(i)}=\cfrac{y^{(i)}(\langle\underline{w},\underline{x}\rangle+b)}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}}$}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

But the code doesn't compile both with pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX. All I get is a couple of 'undefined control sequence' errors like this:

```
Undefined control sequence. ...l{\cfrac{b}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}}$}
Undefined control sequence. ...l{\cfrac{b}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}}$}
Undefined control sequence. ...l{\cfrac{b}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}}$}
Undefined control sequence. ...l{\cfrac{b}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}}$}
Undefined control sequence. ...l{\cfrac{b}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}}$}
Undefined control sequence. ...3984034){$\scalebox{1.5}{\boldsymbol{b}}$}
Undefined control sequence. ...3984034){$\scalebox{1.5}{\boldsymbol{b}}$}
File ended while scanning use of \pst@makenotverbbox.
No file amsmath.tex.
```

I added `\include{amsmath}` to the code cause I know `\cfrac` comes from there but it doesn't solve, I still get the same error... but it's autogenerated, so the syntax must be correct. What's going wrong?

Comment: The fact that it's autogenerated doesn't necessarily mean it's correct ..

Comment: This code is a real mess, and your forgot to load `graphicx`  to make the  `\scalebox` command valid. Furthermore, what's the point of using coordinates  with a precision of 16 decimal digits?

Comment: @Bernard The code is generated by GeoGebra, so blame GeoGebra ...

Comment: Quoting HV's frequently-said comment: "PSTricks code produced by Geogebra is garbage!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not shown the error message just a summary missing the main information.

the first error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \scalebox 
                          
l.15 ...l{\cfrac{b}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}}$}
                                                  
?
```

showing that `\scalebox` is not defined. That comes from the `graphicx` (or `graphics`) package.

adding

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

and re-running produces

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \boldsymbol 
                       {\cfrac {b}{\lVert \underline w\rVert }}
l.16 ...l{\cfrac{b}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}}$}
                                                  
?
```

showing `\boldsymbol` is not defined, this comes from `amsmath` so add

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

That produces

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.16 ...l{\cfrac{b}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}}$}
                                                  
?
```

So change all the incorrect occurrences of `$\scalebox{1.5}{` to `\scalebox{1.5}{$`

This then runs without error

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=5pt 0,linewidth=2.pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-0.75,-0.2)(2.5,1.8)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=0.2,Dy=0.2,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-0.75,-0.2)(2.5,1.8)
\psplot[linewidth=2.pt]{-0.75}{2.5}{(--1.92-1.2*x)/1.6}
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=1pt 1pt](0.,0.)(0.576,0.768)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=1pt 1pt](-0.4,1.19677)(-0.4,0.)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=1pt 1pt](0.992,0.456)(1.4,1.)
\begin{scriptsize}
\rput[bl](-1.2222293167219342,2.0250662487315707){Iperpiano}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](0.,0.)
\rput[bl](0.347674159199165,0.33990526238231566){\scalebox{1.5}{$\boldsymbol{\cfrac{b}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}$}}
\psdots[dotsize=4pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](0.,1.2)
\rput[bl](0.01742007432551912,1.2396098567891212){\darkgray{$D$}}
\rput[bl](-0.5330034004638906,0.5826826926190728){\scalebox{1.5}{$\boldsymbol{b}$}}
\psdots[dotstyle=*](1.4,1.)
\rput[bl](1.4676662731184857,0.9444686670895343){\scalebox{1.5}{$\boldsymbol{x^{(i)}}$}}
\rput[bl](1.2570694653729724,0.6826498697753844){\scalebox{1.5}{$\boldsymbol{d^{(i)}=\cfrac{y^{(i)}(\langle\underline{w},\underline{x}\rangle+b)}{\lVert \underline w\rVert}}$}}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

The resulting output is perhaps not what was intended but that's another issue

[image]

Or if you change the pspicture units from 1cm to 4cm

```
\psset{xunit=4.0cm,yunit=4.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=5pt 0,linewidth=2.pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
```

[image]

Comment: `$\scalebox{1.5}{...}$` to `\scalebox{1.5}{$...$}` actually.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yep I put the full document in once I'd got to the end

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks, luckly it works. For the bad proportions it's enough to change xunit and yunit to something like 4cm-5cm I guess

Comment: @Bafforasta is that mangled display of the error messages from texstudio?